# Auto restart android OS

Tags: android-sdk

I am looking for a mechanism so that I can auto restart my android 4.3 phone at periodic intervals without human intervention.

Is there some way that allows me to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.autoreboot

It needs root permissions.

Comment: +1 worked for me, as far as I know any app that can access the reboot menu will need root permission.